# Django rest framework, request object cannot list all method by dir

Tags: django-rest-framework

In any viewset, `build_absolute_uri` not in `dir(request)` but in `dir(request._request)`. Why `request.build_absolute_uri` call `request._request.build_absolute_uri` ?

```py
class DefaultUrlViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    ...

    def get_queryset(self):
        request = self.request
        assert 'build_absolute_uri' not in dir(request)
        assert 'build_absolute_uri' in dir(request._request)
        assert hasattr(request, 'build_absolute_uri')
        print('???? why hasattr but cannot list it in dir?')
        return super().get_queryset()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`build_absolute_uri` is a method of standard  `HTTPRequest` and DRF's `Request` is Wrapper allowing to enhance a standard `HttpRequest` instance

`Request` puts its wrapped `HTTPRequest` in `_request` attribute.

In the source code of django-rest-framework's [Request](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/request.py#L410) It has overridden `__getattr__` method such that if any attribute does not exist it will try to get it from `self._request`.

```py
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        """
        If an attribute does not exist on this instance, then we also attempt
        to proxy it to the underlying HttpRequest object.
        """
        try:
            return getattr(self._request, attr)
        except AttributeError:
            return self.__getattribute__(attr)
```